# "No trusted certificate found" on Spring Integration SSL Connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a project that uses Spring Integration for TCP connections.

- I produced a .keystore file with keytool -genkey -v -keystore command.
- I produced a .cert file using above keystore with keytool -export command.
- I produced a trustStore file using above cert with keytool -import command.

After this I used keystore and truststore files in my project like this:

```
<bean id="sslContextSupport" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport">
    <constructor-arg value="file:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\produced.keystore"/>
    <constructor-arg value="file:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\producedTrustStore"/>
    <constructor-arg value="TEST1234"/>
    <constructor-arg value="TEST1234"/>
</bean>
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory ...
                               ssl-context-support="sslContextSupport"
                               .../>
```

When I send a request with this config, I'm getting

```
SSLHandshakeException:sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found:No trusted certificate found
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Run with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to debug TLS/SSL problems.

Have you imported the server's cert into the trust store?

See [this test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/88c3d0690eeb45d8224f5c90754537035b5d36d6/spring-integration-ip/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/SocketSupportTests.java#L226-L410) and its comments.